# How to give Roles across servers?

Tags: python, discord, bots

So im currently coding a Discord Bot that works globally. So for example when I Ban someone globally, the person will be banned on every other discord server that the bot is also on.

But now Im trying to make a "global Mute" command. It should give the user the mute role on every server that the bot is on. I have a serverSetup.json file were all the informations are stored like "muterole" or "memberrole"

`{ "1139335633882579027": { "mute_role": 1139356364297220167, "member_role": 1139338847080165406, "invite_link": "https://discord.gg/123" }, "933078112047091753": { "mute_role": 937777431975182376, "member_role": 937776349001678908, "invite_link": "https://discord.gg/123" }, "1028973807240740904": { "mute_role": 1139559797268688896, "member_role": 1139559797268688896, "invite_link": "https://discord.gg/123" } }`

**My current code for the "globalMute" command is this here:**

`@bot.command()
async def globalMute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
mute_role_given = 0

```
for guild in bot.guilds:
    guild_id = str(guild.id)
    if guild_id in server_setups:
        setup_data = server_setups[guild_id]
        mute_role_id = setup_data.get('mute_role')
        if mute_role_id:
            mute_role = guild.get_role(mute_role_id)
            if mute_role and member in guild.members:
                try:
                    await member.add_roles(mute_role, reason="Global Mute")
                    mute_role_given += 1
                except discord.Forbidden:
                    pass

if mute_role_given > 0:
    await ctx.send(f"The User {member.mention} has now on {mute_role_given} Servers the mute Role")
else:
    await ctx.send(f"The User {member.mention} could not get the Mute Role")`
```

And when I now try running it and typing in the chat the command it pops up with this error in the console:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role`

I think that the Bot tries to give me all the roles that are in the serverSetups.json only on the server where I excecuted the command. And thats not what I excpected.

Could anyone help me with this complex problem?

Comment: Did you check if the role actually still exists? Also on a side-note: You can get into a ratelimit very fast with this type of bots if you don't handle them and possible exceptions yourself.

Comment: @Dominik Yes I checked if the Roles still exists because I own these Servers, and I didnt delete them. I know that I can be ratelimeted